# Not able to Query alphanumeric fields from ELASTIC SEARCH using TERMS QUERY

Tags: java, elasticsearch, query-builder, elasticsearch-jest

I am trying to query Alphanumeric values from the index using TERMS QUERY, But it is not giving me the output.

Query:

```
{
  "size" : 10000,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "terms" : {
          "caid" : [ "A100945","A100896" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "fields" : [ "acco", "bOS", "aid", "TTl", "caid" ]
}
```

I want to get all the entries that has caid  A100945 or A100896

The same query works fine for NUmeric fields.

I am not planning to use QueryString/MatchQuery as i am trying to build general query builder that can build query for all the request. Hence am looking to get the entries usinng TERMS Query only.

Note: I am using Java API org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders for building the Query.

eg: QueryBuilders.termQuery("caid", "["A10xxx", "A101xxx"]")

Please help.

Regards,
Mik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have not customized the mappings/analysis for the `caid`-field, then your values are indexed as e.g. `a100945`, `a100896` (note the lowercasing.)

The `terms`-query does *not* do query-time text-analysis, so you'll be searching for `A100945` which does not match `a100945`.

This is quite a common problem, and is explained a bit more in this article on [Troubleshooting Elasticsearch searches, for Beginners](https://www.found.no/foundation/beginner-troubleshooting/).

Answer (score 0):

You better use match query.match query are analyzed[applied default analyzer and query] like

```
QueryBuilders.matchQuery("caid", "["A10xxx", "A101xxx"]");
```